# Node.js res.send is not a function (wechat miniprogram)

Tags: node.js, backend

I am writing a api for my front-end, the process is, frontend send a string to backend, after decode backend send back the code.

```
        const router = require('koa-router')({
            prefix: '/weapp'
        });

        router.post("/openid", async (req, res) => {
        const Ut = require("../common/utils");
        try {
            let grant_type = 'authorization_code'
            let appid = config.appId
            let secret = config.appSecret
            let code = req.accept.headers.accept
            console.log('req code: ', code);
            let opts = {
                url: 'https://api.weixin.qq.com/sns/jscode2session?appid=' + appid + '&secret=' + secret + '&js_code=' + code + '&grant_type=' + grant_type
            }
            let r1 = await Ut.promiseReq(opts);
            r1 = JSON.parse(r1);
            console.log('r1 is:', r1);
            openid = r1.openid
            res.send(openid)
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            res.json('');
        }
      })
```

`res.send(openid)` should send the openid, but what I receive is `{code: -1, error: "res.json is not a function"}`. And I don't see the definition of the variable `res` is overloaded. Help me please~

Comment: good practice to use let instead of var into a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
The code `router.post("/openid", async (req, res) => {` uses Express Framework, but Wechat uses Koa2 framework, so the parameters in `async()` are a bit different.
In Koa2, we should write `router.post("/openid", async (ctx, next) => {`. In this case, ctx.response and ctx.request represent res and req in express respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is getting caught and it runs res.json(''). Try changing it to res.json(null) or res.json({})

Comment: My code is getting caught because in try{} block, res.send(openid) returns am error: TypeError: res.send is not a function. And I don't know how to fix it.